# Randomly got No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome, cors, cross-domain

I build a CDN server with EXPRESS.js , put it on subdomain, and use `cors` package to enable CORS

```
var app = express();

app.use(cors({
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS",
})); 

function shouldCompress (req, res) {
    if (req.headers['x-no-compression']) return false
    return compression.filter(req, res)
}
app.use(compression({filter: shouldCompress}))
app.use(requestIp.mw());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '5mb', extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.text({type: 'text/plain',limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(cookieParser());
```

But sometimes my site didn't load correctly due to CORS policy.
I test those links with `https://www.test-cors.org` with both `GET` and `OPTIONS`. and everything is fine.

[image]

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cdn.boghrat.com//adm/notif.html' from origin 'https://boghrat.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

[image]

Comment: Could you try not adding `OPTIONS` to the methods list? e.g. `app.use(cors())` and send one options request to your application to see if it works? If you can get it to work with zero configuration, the next step would be to add configuration and see if it works. That would help debug if there's a simple misconfiguration at play.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,OPTIONS,UPDATE,DELETE"
  );
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, token"
  );
  next();
});
```

Comment: indeed, OP needs to allow some headers, not only methods